# What is the best way to check the type of a Scala variable?

Tags: scala

Is there a simple way to determine if a variable is a list, dictionary, or something else? Basically I am getting an object back that may be either type and I need to be able to tell the difference.

In Python, we have "Type()", "Typeof()" that

```
scala> val c: String = "Hello world"
```

Is there any way to determine : Typeof(c) to print : String

Comment: Don't do this! Let the compiler worry about types for you! Life can be so much better!

Comment: Best part of the nice long linked answer is the last line: `It would be better, however, to be more specific about what you want to accomplish, so that the answer can be more to the point.`

Comment: @TravisBrown I think this is useful mainly for debugging. Once I was playing with an implicit function converting a String to Int, and I ended up with a Java null-pointer exception for an Int. Turned out the input for my implicit was a `null: String`, which I forgot to convert to 0. In such cases it's useful to be able to print the type of you `null`. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe you can just use:

```
c.getClass
```